# I am getting a grey popup box in the middle of the screen in mac android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I am getting a grey box in the middle of the screen in mac android studio, and It's stuck there even I am minimised android studio,

I am getting this box when I tried to navigate to any method via the shortcut (command + mouse click).
I have this specification in the Mac system :

- macOS Big Sur (version 11.0.1)
- Android Studio Arctic fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 (the latest stable version),

can anyone have this same issue? please let me know you solve this anyhow

[Android Studio Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvf6CN8LC63hHG-EWc1pdR1_tbyJ6Kd_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can confirm the same on macOS Big Sur (version 11.6.2) Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, built on November 21, 2021

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 (Monterey OS 12.1)

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy (tab) -> Accessibility

Uncheck all the apps in the "Allow the apps below to control your computer" section. In my case, it was just Grammarly.

[Security & Privacy Dialog Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBvos.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and reinstalling Android Studio didn't help.

I've tried method above, but all apps were already unchecked. So, instead I added Android Studio to the list and it worked.